Can a Linux shell script written in UTF-16 format with BOM?
Can a Linux shell script written in UTF-16 format with BOM? I want to include some UTF-16 characters in the comment.
Update
In my server, it shows the following error:
-bash: ./test-unicode.sh: cannot execute binary file


I'm pretty sure it can't. A script normally starts with a shebang, and the OS won't skip over the BOM to look for it.

It could also depend on which shell you use.


Can a Linux shell script written in UTF-16 format with BOM?

Theoretically yes, practically any shell nowadays uses ASCII, not unicode or any other advanced encoding.

I want to include some UTF-16 characters in the comment.

The magic of multibyte encoding like UTF-8 is that it includes all ASCII characters as-is. Use UTF-8 instead and include the same unicode characters.
Becuase "UTF-16 characters" is mentioned, check https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ .

Perhaps in some more detail; UTF-8 and UTF-16 are different serialization formats, which can represent exactly the same characters. There are no "UTF-16 characters", only Unicode characters (or more strictly speaking code points) and yes, you are probably better off preferring UTF-8 for serialization of your shell scripts.
